# SIPP with Proxy Media

Tags: sip

I am using SIPP to load test a proxy media server. I am not able to set the IP and port of the proxy media server on the SDP generated by SIPP,
I get the below error,

./sipp -sn uac -d 10000 -l 1000 -i 192.12.24.32 -p 50970 -mi 65.67.8.99 -mp 48321 10.12.24.32:5060 -sf uac_pcap.xml

Unable to bind audio RTP socket (IP=65.67.8.99, port=48322), errno = 99 (Cannot assign requested address).

```
  v=0
  o=user1 53655765 2353687637 IN IP[local_ip_type] [local_ip]
  s=-
  t=0 0
  c=IN IP[local_ip_type] [media_ip]
  m=audio [auto_media_port] RTP/AVP 8
  a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in either sdp (sdp probably should be one of your tags, btw) or sipp but the sipp documentation says:

> -mi              : Set the local media IP address (default: local primary host IP address)
>
> -mp              : Set the local RTP echo port number. Default is 6000.

This means that sipp tries to open the port designed by -mp on the **local** IP designed by -mi.

From what you said I understand the IP:port combination you give in -mi/-mp to be the IP:port combination on the media server, not on the machine running sipp. This means that sipp is trying to open a port on an IP owned by the destination, hence why it "Cannot assign requested address".

The IP:port of the media server should not be part of the SDP generated by sipp. Sipp should describe its end of the media session, then the reply to the INVITE should contain an SDP coming in from 10.12.24.32:5060 with an SDP describing the other end of the media session, including the IP:port of the media server.

Think about it. In a real call you would know the destination SIP address (or sips or...) but you would have no idea of where their media would be. The exchange of SIP message is what establishes that (through an exchange of SDPs), so your sipp SDP should not contain information about a remote media server that it would not know about in a real call.

Try this*:

```
./sipp -d 10000 -l 1000 -i 192.12.24.32 -p 50970 -mi 192.12.24.32 -mp 48321 10.12.24.32:5060 -sf uac_pcap.xml
```

*You use both -sn to specify a built in scenario and -sf to specify a scenario file. In other word you are specifying two scenarios, so I removed the built in scenario from the line. Maybe you have good reasons for it to be here that I know nothing about, in which case put it back in.